# Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE$database' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

This is my db.php file

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'my_testdb';
?>
```

and this is my createdb.php

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect tp MySQL:".
    mysqli_connect_error();
}

    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE".$database;
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo "Database created successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Error creating database:".mysqli_error($con);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And when i run the createDB.php in chrome it comes up with this message:

> Error creating database:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE$database' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error happnes because you need to put a space between DATABASE and database name

```
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$database;
                     //^here a space
```

Comment: do also mention about SQL Injection. This code prone to it

Comment: Yes that's true but i didn't mention since the code get its text from a previusly defined variable, there is no user interaction actually